# How to fix an 'Uncaught Error: invalid address' error?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I deployed my contract to Goerli test net. Deploying was successful. And I tested it in Remix.

Contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Test{
    
    string private str;
    
    constructor() public {
        str = " ";
    }
    
    function getStr() public view returns(string memory  _str){
        _str = str;
    }
    
    function setStr(string memory  _str) public{
        str = _str;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to make a web interface using web3 and MetaMask.

```html
<script>
        ethereum.enable()
        var abi = [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_str",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setStr",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getStr",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_str",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
    ];
        var address = 0x4316d047388e61EBC3Ed34DFf4cEE215840decDa;
        var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
        var TestC = myContract.at(address);
        console.log(TestC);
    var x = TestC.getStr();
</script>
```

And when I ran it, it returned:

> Uncaught Error: invalid address
>
> at c (inpage.js:1)
>
> at inputCallFormatter (inpage.js:1)
>
> at inpage.js:1
>
> at Array.map ()
>
> at o.formatInput (inpage.js:1)
>
> at o.toPayload (inpage.js:1)
>
> at w.e [as call] (inpage.js:1)
>
> at u.call (inpage.js:1)
>
> at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
>
> at (index):46

What I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `address` should be a hex string, not a literal hex number - even though it is eventually turned into a number by the ethereum node.

Try this instead:

```js
var address = '0x4316d047388e61EBC3Ed34DFf4cEE215840decDa';
```

Comment: Have similar issue in the end of 2022: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140205/invalid-address-error-on-a-call-of-the-contract-which-has-been-deployed-and-mine

Your suggestion didn't solve the issue. Do you have thoughts on what else might not be correct?